# Convolution of L1 & L2 function: definition

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis

A book that I'm reading makes the following statement that I'm not sure how to understand:
On $\mathbb R^n$, if $f\in L1$ and $g\in L2$, we have:
$$\widehat{f*g}=\hat f \hat g$$
How do I read it?
I know that the assumptions imply $\hat f$ is continuous and bounded, $\hat g\in L2$ so that the product on the right-hand side is a well-defined $L2$-function. Hence it is the Fourier transform of an $L2$-function $(\hat f \hat g\check{)}$ which, apparently, is equal to $f*g$.
For all I know it could be the definition of $f*g$ in this case. But is $f*g$ actually defined by an a.e. convergent integral as in the case $f,g\in L1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: notice that in order to define $f\ast g$ it is enough to assume $f$ and $g$ measurable such that $y\mapsto f(x-y)g(y)$ is in $L^1$. (Of course it is sufficient to assume $f,g\in L^1$ by Young's theorem, but is not necessary.)

Comment: Posted before I'd finished typing...

Comment: Thanks, and sorry about the non-comment above. Technical mistake by me. Maybe I get it now - is it like this?
Suppose f, g positive. I want to show that $\int f(y)g(x-y) dy$ and that the resulting function of x is L2. So we integrate its square w.r.t. x:
$$\int |\int f(y)g(x-y) dy|^2 dx=\int \int \int f(y)f(z)g(x-y)g(x-z) dy dz dx$$ $$=\int f(y) f(z)\int\int g(x-y) g(x-z) dx dy dz\leq \int\int f(y)f(z) \|g\|_2^2 dy dz=\|f\|_1^2\|g\|_2^2$$
By Hölder.
Am i then correct in thinking that to show the equality in the question I should approximate g with functions in $L1\cap L2$?

Comment: your are correct!